# Find all files with integers in the name that are greater than a certain value, preferably in a LINUX setting

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, find

Given a directory with files having names of the form "TestName[INT]" where [INT] is some number, how can I find all files with numbers in their name and that number is greater than a given value? For example, if I wanted to find all files where [INT] is greater than five which could possibly return "TestName9" and "TestName3190321".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming filenames will be like TestName always, script will be,

```
arr=()
for filename in `ls <input dir>`
do

num=`echo $filename | cut -f3 -d 'e'`

if [ "${num}" -gt 5 ]
then
    arr+=("$filename")
fi

done
echo ${arr[@]}
```

This should serve the purpose.